# Java: Start a socket server class with the port as an argument

Tags: java, sockets, server, arguments

So i have a load balancer and when a server is full of clients i want to create a new multithread server programmatically by passing the server port as an argument.

This is how im trying to start a new server instance

```
int newport = 4001
SMTPserver server = new SMTPserver();
server.SMTPserver(port);
```

this is my server

```
public class SMTPserver {
    public static Socket connsock = null;
    public static int port;

//     SMTPserver(int port) {
//        this.port = port;
//    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server is running on port " + port);

        while (true) {

            try {

                // accepting client socket
                connsock = serverSocket.accept();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

my question is how to start this server with the giver port argument? is this code correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing 0 to the ServerSocket constructor, so it will choose an available port. You need to pass a non zero port number if you want to use a specific port.

You could do it like this:

```
public class SMTPserver {
    public Socket connsock = null;
    public int port;

    public SMTPserver(int port) {
        this.port = port;

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Server is running on port " + port);

        while (true) {

            try {

                // accepting client socket
                connsock = serverSocket.accept();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that I'm assigning the port parameter to the port field, and then passing it to the ServerSocket constructor.

Comment: this seems to be good but when im trying to start the server instance at the line *SMTPserver server = new SMTPserver();* i get ```constructor SMTPserver in class SMTPserver cannot be applied to given types;
  required: int
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length```

Comment: You need to pass the port to the constructor, i.e. `server = new SMPTServer(4001);`

Comment: perferct thank you. But how do i start this instance?

Comment: It starts in the constructor